# Generate a composite unique constraint/index, in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I need a composite unique constraint for my entity's `Name` property, which is unique per `Category` (for which it has an FK).

So something like this:

```
entityTypeBuilder
  .HasIndex(i => new { i.Name, i.Category.Id })
  .IsUnique();
```

But this fails when I generate a migration, because of the `Category.Id` navigation property.

I know I can hardcode the values as strings, but I don't want to lose the static typing.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a foreign key for Category of `CategoryId` on the entity in question and use that in the index builder instead of the navigation property.

Comment: Yeah but that's messy. Is that the only option?

Comment: Why do you think that is messy? Adding a foreign key property is not messy, why do you think that? @grokky

Comment: @grokky - I'd argue that not defining the foreign key property is messy. The [EF docs recommend it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#no-foreign-key-property), and, I'd rather not introduce a shadow property.

Comment: @kizilsu It adds an infrastructure-related property to a domain-related class. It's messy. I don't like it, but it seems that this is the only available option, without giving up on static typing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using your entity models directly into your system. I recommend you that you should seperete your db and business logic layers. In business logic models you don't need to keep that foreign key property @grokky

Comment: @kizilsu No I'm not doing that. But the point of an ORM is to be shielded from the workings of the database. Sometimes that's not possible, like in this case.

Answer (score 23):

As soon as you know the shadow property name, you can use (at least in EF Core 1.1.0) the string based `HasIndex` method [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_HasIndex_System_String___)

```
public virtual IndexBuilder HasIndex(params string[] propertyNames)
```

e.g.

```
entityTypeBuilder
  .HasIndex("Name", "CategoryId")
  .IsUnique();
```

Same for `HasAlternateKey`:

```
entityTypeBuilder
  .HasAlternateKey("Name", "CategoryId");
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now, as I said in the question though, you lose static typing. Maybe this is the only way.

Comment: For who's reading. You dont lose static typing. Just use nameof(Type.Property)

Comment: lose the "}" bracket though.
entityTypeBuilder.HasIndex("Name", "CategoryId").IsUnique();

Comment: @BenVertonghen Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The detailed answer is only in the comments of the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/40771546/9641435

So I wanted to share the actual code that you could use if you do not want to lose static typing:

```
entityTypeBuilder
  .HasIndex(nameof(MyType.Name), nameof(MyType.CategoryId))
  .IsUnique();
```

or:

```
entityTypeBuilder
  .HasAlternateKey(nameof(MyType.Name), nameof(MyType.CategoryId));
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to Ivan's excellent response:

If you define the foreign key upfront, you can at least control the name association

```
const string auditForeignKey = "AuditId";
builder.HasOne(e => e.Audit)
       .WithMany(e => e.AuditLocations)
       .HasForeignKey(auditForeignKey);

builder.HasIndex(auditForeignKey, nameof(AuditLocation.LocationId)).IsUnique();
```